# $\Gamma$ function is continuous on $]0,\infty [$

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to show that $\Gamma$ is continuous on $]0,\infty [$.

Let $x>0$,
$$|\Gamma(x+h)-\Gamma(x)|\leq\int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}|t^h-1|dt=\underbrace{\int_0^1 t^{x-1}e^{-t}\underbrace{|t^h-1|}_{\leq |h|}dt}_{\underset{h\to 0}{\longrightarrow0 }}+\int_1^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}|t^h-1|dt$$

If $t> 1$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|t^h-1|\sim \ln(t)h\leq th$,
therefore, if $|h|<\delta$, 
$$\int_1^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}|t^h-1|dt\leq h\int_1^\infty t^{x}e^{-t}dt\leq |h|\Gamma(x+1)\underset{h\to 0}{\longrightarrow }0 .$$

We conclude that $$|\Gamma(x+h)-\Gamma(x)| \underset{h\to 0}{\longrightarrow }0$$
and thus $\Gamma$ is continuous on $]0,\infty [$.

**Questions**

1) Is this proof correct ?

2) I can't use theorem of dominated convergence. But If I were authorized to use it, would it be possible to use it here ? And if yes, how ?

Thanks,

Comment: In your first inequality, shoudn't it be $\displaystyle \leq \int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}|t^h-1|dt$ ?

Comment: There is a shorter way: $\log\Gamma$ is a convex function on $\mathbb{R}^+$ by the Bohr-Mollerup theorem, hence $\log\Gamma$ is continuous, hence $\Gamma$  is continuous.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM: yes, thanks :-)

Comment: I am sorry. How do you get $|t^h-1|\sim \ln(t)h$?

Comment: By mean-value theorem, I get $|t^h-1| = \ln(t)ht^c$, for some $c \in (0,h).$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: Yes, your proof is correct:

2: For dominated convergence, you need a dominating function.  Consider the function
$$
g(x) = \max\{t^{x + \delta}e^t,t^{x - \delta}e^t\}
$$
Where we can choose any $\delta \in (0, x)$.  Once we know that this function is integrable, dominated convergence applies.